# Installing OCS (Openshift Container Storage) on Openshift 4.2 pre release cluster

Tags: openshift, storage

How do you create a storage cluster for a bare metal openshift cluster using ocs operator? I have installed the operators using:

```
oc create -f ./deploy/deploy-with-olm.yaml
```

but the sample YAML to create storage cluster in the next step has a type `gp2`, which is for AWS I guess, because I tried and it failed. I need to do it for a bare metal openshift 4.2 cluster. Any thoughts?

I have a 3 master and 3 node configuration, and I have labelled the worker nodes as storage nodes. I am expecting a CNS type installation (I have installed GlusterFS CNS on Openshift 3.11 before) using local storage from worker nodes. Please let me know how to accomplish this using the ocs operator.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but if your worker node have available block device you could try this

https://blog.openshift.com/ocs-4-2-in-ocp-4-2-14-upi-installation-in-rhv/

If you don't have device available you may create them with loop device but this start to look really hackish. (https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-create-virtual-block-device-loop-device-filesystem-in-linux/)